# Can Visual Studio mixed mode debugging be attached to a Jupyter notebook to debug C++ and Python simultaneously?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2017

I have a Jupyter notebook running Python with my own C++ extensions.

Can I attach the Visual Studio debugger to debug Python and C++ simultaneously?

Both of the projects are in my solution and the mixed mode debugger works just fine when I run within VS.  Would love to do the same on a Jupyter notebook running the same code.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this (i.e., debugging a C++ extension for Python from a Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio Code)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Python Visual Debugger for Jupyter Notebooks described [here](https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/the-visual-python-debugger-for-jupyter-notebooks-youve-always-wanted-761713babc62).
(Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer)